How to identify and fix wrong imports and versions? - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
I develop my first app using Android Studio in Kotlin and in LogCat I get a lot of errors. Interestingly, the app builds and works as expected, but these errors annoy me:
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView$AndroidComposeViewTranslationCallback>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/translation/ViewTranslationCallback;
 at androidx.compose.runtime.Composition androidx.compose.ui.platform.Wrapper_androidKt.setContent(androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView, androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionContext, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function2) (Wrapper.android.kt:77)
 at void androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.ensureCompositionCreated() (ComposeView.android.kt:251)
 at void androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onAttachedToWindow() (ComposeView.android.kt:283)
 at void android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(android.view.View$AttachInfo, int) (View.java:20104)
 at void android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(android.view.View$AttachInfo, int) (ViewGroup.java:4181)
 at void android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(android.view.View$AttachInfo, int) (ViewGroup.java:4188)
   uid=10184(com.namify.namipay) identical 1 line
 at void android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(android.view.View$AttachInfo, int) (ViewGroup.java:4188)
 at void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals() (ViewRootImpl.java:2296)
 at void android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal() (ViewRootImpl.java:1961)
 at void android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run() (ViewRootImpl.java:8718)
 at void android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(long) (Choreographer.java:988)
 at void android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(int, long) (Choreographer.java:765)
 at void android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(long, int) (Choreographer.java:700)
 at void android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run() (Choreographer.java:967)
 at void android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:873)
 at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:99)
 at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:216)
 at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:7266)
 at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
 at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:494)
 at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:975)

I get many more if them (here just the unique headlines):
2024-05-14 13:42:22.638 Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView$AndroidComposeViewTranslationCallback>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/translation/ViewTranslationCallback;
2024-05-14 13:42:23.500 Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<YL2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/PacProcessor;
2024-05-14 13:42:24.892 Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<D25>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/window/extensions/core/util/function/Consumer;

And very often:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.window.extensions.core.util.function.Consumer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.chrome-0AY9YoeB18qQ5hdFN2N6kA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.chrome-0AY9YoeB18qQ5hdFN2N6kA==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.android.chrome-0AY9YoeB18qQ5hdFN2N6kA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]

I found a few post with similar issues and they tried to change dependencies version in build.gradle.kts but I have no clue where to look for the causing import and what version is needed. And why the dependency is missing?
I also did every update Android Studio was offering me.
How can I identify the reason? How to identify the causing dependency? How to identify a working version number for this dependency to fix this issue?

Does this answer your question? Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

"How can I identify the reason?" -- Android changes over time, including its API surface. Android and its libraries have a system for dealing with this. However, that system results in some log entries at runtime, depending on the version of Android your code is running on. So, for example, on Android 10 and older, there is no android.view.translation.ViewTranslationCallback interface, so you'll get messages like your first one, but the library will work around the limitation in that case.

@Leviathan Sadly not. I tried cleaning and re-build with no success. Also the other solutions there did not work for me.

@CommonsWare This helps me to understand. Thanks. So this are not really errors but more some kind of warning? You are right, with a more recent Android version on the connected device, there are less of these messages.

I have not looked recently to see what logging level Google used for this particular message. Android logs lots of things at error severity that, from the standpoint of app developers, mean nothing. If you have other symptoms (e.g., app crashes, app runs very slowly), looking at system-level log messages can be useful. However, on their own, Logcat messages logged by other OS processes than your app often mean very little.

@CommonsWare Thanks again. The error is in my app (I filter the log for only my app messages). Especially the fact that it is a full stack trace and none of the mentioned files is any of my Kotlin files made me worry about this. Is there a list of common APIs missing in previous versions so I can identify that issue more easily? I mean, how to find out if I did an error or if it is just Android APIs missing and then automatically worked around? And can I identify what of my code triggered the issue? The stack does not mention any of my source files.

"The error is in my app" -- the error is from your process. "Is there a list of common APIs missing in previous versions so I can identify that issue more easily?" -- I do not know what would qualify for "common", and there are hundreds to thousands in any given release. "I mean, how to find out if I did an error or if it is just Android APIs missing and then automatically worked around?" -- if you are experiencing other symptoms, such as actual crashes, that seem to be tied to the functionality here, then maybe this is related.

"And can I identify what of my code triggered the issue?" -- this is coming from AndroidComposeView, so it would be from either your setContent() call that kicks off Compose or from some other use of ComposeView to wrap some View. More generally, if you are going to react this way every time you see something odd in your process' Logcat, you will be very uncomfortable with Android app development. I wish Google had better logging discipline, but they do not.

As luck would have it, I just ran into the same sort of NoSuchMethodError stack trace. In my case, though, it was tied to an actual crash, and it was logged at error (red) severity in Logcat. Searching Google on NoSuchMethodError and the class mentioned in the error returned https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/322214617, which indicated that my problem was because this project was on an old Compose BOM.
